# JQuery returning string not array, despite apparent logic of code...why?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, post

I'm revising code written by another developer. Here he collects values and turns them from an array (`dataId`) into a comma-separated string:

```
$("#retrieve_works_form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#toggle_search_terms').trigger('click');
    var dataId = new Array();
    $('li.nw').each(function() {
        var thisDataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
        dataId.push(thisDataId);
    });
    $('li.added_gallery_item').each(function() {
        var thisDataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
        dataId.push(thisDataId);
    });
    $('#returned_gallery_work_ids').val(dataId.join(','));
```

The `$_POST['returned_gallery_work_ids']` therefore holds a comma-separated string of the values in the `dataId` array. I want to revise this so it simply returns the array, with each element in a sequential index. I would think that doing this would do the trick:

```
$('#returned_gallery_work_ids').val(dataId);
```

...but it doesn't; it returns a comma-separate string of values, no different than what is returned when `dataId.join(',')` is the argument of the `.val()` operator.

There are really two questions here:

1. Why is the result a comma-separated string in each case?
2. How do I make it return the `dataId` array?

[The second question is the truly necessary question, but I want to understand the mechanics of what's taking place here.]

Comment: (1) `val()` expects a string, so whatever gets passed is treated as one. The `toString()` method is likely being invoked on `dataId`, and it's default behavior is the same as `.join(',')`. (2) What is `#returned_gallery_work_ids`? If it's an element, again, the DOM element expects a string for its `value` property. If you want a true array, then assigning it to an element as a value isn't going to work. You can't POST a JavaScript array to the server -- you need a string representation for PHP to interpret, perhaps as it is, or JSON.

Comment: Notice that  'var dataId = new Array();' is on line 4 of the code; 'toString()' is found nowhere in the example.

Comment: Deep in the source code for `val()`, the input is coerced into a string via `dataId + ""`. In order to do the concatenation, `toString()` is implicitly called on `dataId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When storing a value of any kind in an input, it's stored as a string, so if you later retrieve it, you'll need to split it:

```
var galleryArray = $("#returned_gallery_work_ids").val().split(',');
```

Or in PHP on the server side, you'll use this:

```
$galleryArray = explode( ",", $_POST['returned_gallery_work_ids'] );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's also worth noting that an array variable in javascript is just a comma-delimited string of values.

Comment: Does that mean that 'dataId.join(',')' is redundant, and therefore 'dataId' is all that needs to be passed to the '.val()' operator?

Comment: Ah, you've answered my question...the previous developers code is redundant. All I need to pass in is 'dataId' and convert it to an array where I receive it elsewhere as POST data. Thanks!

Comment: @Tom: I would keep the explicit `.join(',')`, as you and future developers may have an easier time remembering how that works instead of relying on the framework and your memory.

Comment: I'd agree with @Cᴏʀʏ that you should keep the `.join(',')`, but otherwise, it will definitely work to explode in PHP once it reaches the server. If my answer is sufficient, please help me out by upvoting it :)

Comment: To clarify my statement about how javascript stores arrays - they are just a special kind of object. For example, you can create an array using what's called an 'array literal' which essentially stores the value you pass just as JS would store it: `var myArray = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];` So there is a difference between a string and an array, but it's just those square brackets. Anyway, you'll still want to use the `join` method because it's technically an object you're working with, so you'll want to treat it as such.